# Compiling Issues, saying that it is illegal start and expecting ; on both the constructors

Tags: java

error: ';' expected
illegal start of expression

These are the two errors im getting within the program on both getGrid and checkGrid
Cannot seem to figure out what the problem is and what is causing it.
help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Aleko_SudokuChecker
  {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("\nWelcome to the Sudoku Checker v1.0!\n");
System.out.print("\nThis program checks simple, small, 4x4 Sudoku grids for\n");
System.out.print("correctness. Each column, row and 2x2 region contains the numbers\n");
System.out.print("1 through 4 only once.\n\n");
System.out.print("To check your sudoku, enter your board one row at a time, with\neach digit separated by a space. Hit ENTER at the end of a row.\n");
SudokuChecker foo = new SudokuChecker();
foo.getGrid();
foo.checkGrid();


public void getGrid()
{

        System.out.print("\nEnter Row 1: ");
    int i = in.nextInt();
        int j = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 2: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int i1 = in.nextInt();
        int i2 = in.nextInt();
        int i3 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 3: ");
        int i4 = in.nextInt();
        int i5 = in.nextInt();
        int i6 = in.nextInt();
        int i7 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 4: ");
        int i8 = in.nextInt();
        int i9 = in.nextInt();
        int i10 = in.nextInt();
        int i11 = in.nextInt();
}



public void checkGrid()
{
    System.out.print("\nThank you. Now checking ... \n");

    int x = 0;



    int i12 = i + j + n + i1;
    int i13 = i4 + i5 + i8 + i9;
    int i14 = k + m + i2 + i3;
    int i15 = i6 + i7 + i10 + i11;

    int i16 = i + j + k + m;
    int i17 = n + i1 + i2 + i3;
    int i18 = i4 + i5 + i6 + i7;
    int i19 = i8 + i9 + i10 + i11;

    int i20 = i + n + i4 + i8;
    int i21 = j + i1 + i5 + i9;
    int i22 = k + i2 + i6 + i10;
    int i23 = m + i3 + i7 + i11;
    if (i12 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-1:PASS");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-1:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if (i13 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-2:PASS");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nReg-2:FAIL");
        x = x +1;
    }
    if (i14 == 10) 
    {
    System.out.print("\nREG-3:PASS");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-3:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if (i15 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-4:PASS\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nREG-4:FAIL\n");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if (i16 == 10) 
    {
            System.out.print("\nROW-1:PASS");
        }
    else 
    {   
            System.out.print("\nROW-1:FAIL");
        x = x+1;    
    }
    if (i17 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nROW-2:PASS");
        } 
    else 
    {
            System.out.print("\nROW-2:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
    }
        if(i18 == 10) 
    {
            System.out.print("\nROW-3:PASS");
        } 
    else 
    {
            System.out.print("\nROW-3:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if (i19 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nROW-4:PASS\n");

    } 
    else 
    {
            System.out.print("\nROW-4:FAIL\n");
        x = x+1;
    }
        if (i20 == 10) 
    {
            System.out.print("\nCOL-1:PASS");
        }    
    else 
    {
            System.out.print("\nCOL-1:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
        }    
    if (i21 == 10) 
    {
            System.out.print("\nCOL-2:PASS");
        } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nCOL-2:FAIL");
    x = x+1;
    }
        if (i22 == 10) 
    {
            System.out.print("\nCOL-3:PASS");
    } 
    else 
    {
            System.out.print("\nCOL-3:FAIL");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if (i23 == 10) 
    {
        System.out.print("\nCOL-4:PASS\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\nCOL-4:FAIL\n");
        x = x+1;
    }
    if ((i12 == 10) && (i13 == 10) && (i14 == 10) && (i15 == 10) && (i16 == 10) && (i17 == 10) && (i18 == 10) && (i19 == 10) && (i20 == 10) && (i21 == 10) && (i22 == 10) && (i23 == 10)) {
            System.out.print("\nCongratulations!\nThis Sudoku is valid.\n\n");    
    }       
    else 
    {
             System.out.print("\nSorry.\nThis Sudoku is invalid.\n\n");
    }
}


 }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket of the main method before starting the next method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close the `main()` method with a brace "}" after `foo.checkGrid();` and before you start the new method `public void getGrid()`.